# Knowledge Base with SharePoint - Communication site or team site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, communication-site

We are currently facing the challenge to choose the most suitable base for our knowledge base in SharePoint. I don't know if we need a website with Microsoft/Office 365 groups link or a communication website. I have done some reading and am now much more confused.

The following sites can be created:

- Team site (with 365 group)
- Communication site
- Modern team site (without 365 group) can only be created via Admin Center
- Classic (Legacy)

The main difference is probably whether a Microsoft/Office 365 group is connected or not. However, I don't know if there are critical limitations if we use a communication/team site now.

We have the following requirements / we would like to use the following:

- Website pages as a base (we don't want to use word documents or anything like that)
- Everything should be structured with content types (all pages are in one library and are supplemented by metadata)
- Predefined filters shall be linked in the navigation to give the users an overview
- External customers should be allowed to view certain areas and specific individual elements

So what are the recommendations? What should be considered for the two different pages?
What are your experiences? Are there any limitations or other stumbling blocks?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, both the team site and the communication site meet.

In addition, you can check the feature Comparison between them:

[image]

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/team-site-or-communication-site#feature-comparison

Comment: Thank you! I have already read through this distinction, is the first google search result. However, I would like to know if there are any distinctions beyond that. What is more sustainable? Are there any limitations that are not obvious at first sight or which the author considered irrelevant or not so prominent and therefore left them out? I would not like to stumble over a restriction when our knowledge base is already in productive use. For example, what are the differences and pros and cons between SharePoint Groups and Microsoft 365 Groups in terms of the SharePoint side?

Comment: If you are using office 365 group connected site, several other services are created with the SharePoint Site including an Exchange Mailbox, OneNote Notebook and Planner plan. Security across these Services is controlled by a security object in Azure Active Directory which can be managed directly in the SharePoint Site or the other services. Instead, a Communication Site does not include an Office 365 Group and security is managed by the SharePoint security group model. Refer to:https://medium.com/provisionpoint/why-would-you-create-a-sharepoint-site-without-an-office-365-group-a162ad3499b4

Comment: Okay, thank you for this summary. I would like to know, if this has any critical impact on the sharing functionality (with external users / guests) ...

Comment: No, exactly same on the sharing.

Comment: If you find any answer helpful to you, please remember to mark it as answer.

Thank you for your understanding.